# Google Dataproc Jobs Never Cancel, Stop, or Terminate

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have been using Google Dataproc for a few weeks now and since I started I had a problem with canceling and stopping jobs.

It seems like there must be some server other than those created on cluster setup, that keeps track of and supervises jobs.

I have never had a process that does its job without error actually stop when I hit stop in the dev console.  The spinner just keeps spinning and spinning.

*Cluster restart or stop does nothing, even if stopped for hours.*

Only when the cluster is entirely deleted will the jobs disappear... (But wait there's more!)  If you create a new cluster with the same settings, before the previous cluster's jobs have been deleted, the old jobs will start on the new cluster!!!

I have seen jobs that terminate on their own due to OOM errors restart themselves after cluster restart!  (with no coding for this sort of fault tolerance on my side)

**How can I forcefully stop Dataproc jobs? (`gcloud beta dataproc jobs kill` does not work)**

**Does anyone know what is going on with these seemingly related issues?**

**Is there a special way to shutdown a Spark job to avoid these issues?**

Comment: If you don't try to cancel/stop the job, is it able to terminate "normally" by itself eventually and show up as "Succeeded" in the dev console? In cases where the cluster is experiencing problems and fails to respond to a cancellation request, the job metadata indeed may continue to show up in the managed service even if the cluster itself isn't actually running the job, but also hasn't reported the non-running status. When it looked like old jobs started on new clusters, did you confirm that work really started on it, or did it just appear so from the dev console?

Comment: If you have more detailed identifiers like project ids, job ids, cluster names, etc., you can send them to Google's teams at dataproc-feedback@google.com for more detailed troubleshooting.

Comment: @BAR Sincere apologies for the troubles. By chance, can you shoot us an email (dataproc-feedback@google.com) with some additional details on your clusters and/or jobs? We'd like to dig into this a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: @DennisHuo: I am experiencing the exact same issue since last week only, are there any details of interest I could give to you ? Thanks

Comment: You can send project IDs and job ids to dataproc-feedback@google.com

Answer (score 1):

**Jobs keep running**

In some cases, errors have not been successfully reported to the Cloud Dataproc service. Thus, if a job fails, it appears to run forever even though it (has probably) failed on the back end. This should be fixed by a soon-to-be released version of Dataproc in the next 1-2 weeks.

**Job starts after restart**

This would be unintended and undesirable. We have tried to replicate this issue and cannot. If anyone can replicate this reliably, we'd like to know so we can fix it! This may (is provably) be related to the issue above where the job has failed but appears to be running, even after a cluster restarts.

**Best way to shutdown**

Ideally, the best way to shutdown a Cloud Dataproc cluster is to terminate the cluster and start a new one. If that will be problematic, you can try a bulk restart of the Compute Engine VMs; it will be much easier to create a new cluster, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answers James.  I am still having problems with never ending jobs, and starts after restart, although in some ways the problem appears to have gotten better.  I have to disagree with your last point on shutdown, but fortunately this does not seem to be an issue anymore.

Comment: Let me check on the never-ending jobs and starts after restart.

Comment: Ok, I misspoke, my apologies. It sounds like our release this week will likely address the never-ending jobs. Most likely, it is due to a problem where some errors have not been successfully reported to the Dataproc agent running on the cluster. That makes it seem like they are running forever, even though they have failed. By chance, if you look @ the App Master have they indeed failed? I'm going to amend my text above to clarify the specific case about errors.